# Excel VBA variable variable names

Tags: excel, vba

I create a lot of tables in my macro. So I am trying to create a module , table_mod , that generates tables and places it three rows below the existing last row and I plan to call the table_mod whenever I need to create tables. But I am running into the fact that I need my variables to be dependent on the table name that the user gives.  For example:

```
Sub Main()


' Below are all the data that my macro will generate in its number crunching

var_12_count = "Jordan"
var_13_count = "Kobe"

var_21_count ="Rings"

var_22_count = 6
var_23_count = 5

var_title_count = "This table lists the number of rings won by Jordan and Kobe"


var_12_transpose = "Rings"

var_21_transpose = "Jordan"
var_31_transpose = "Kobe"

var_22_transpose = 6
var_32_transpose = 5

var_title_transpose = "This is the transpose of the previous table"


' My intention is to call table commands like this to spit out the earlier generated data in nicely formatted tables.    

table_mod(2,3,"count")
table_mod(3,2,"transpose")



End Sub

Sub table_mod(row As Long, column As Long, name As String)


 Set wb As ActiveWorkbook
 Set ws As wb.ActiveSheet

With ws

lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


.Cells(lr+3,1).Value =  var_title_&name


For i = 1 To row
        For j = 1 To column

               .Cells(lr+6+i,j).Value = var_&CStr(i)&CStr(j)&_&name

        Next j 
Next i

End With

End Sub
```

The output should look like

```
 This table lists the number of rings won by Jordan and Kobe


        Jordan  Kobe
 Rings    6      5    




This is the transpose of the previous table


         Rings
  Jordan   6
  Kobe     5
```

But I don't know how to combine the variable values with strings so VBA would know to read the values from the correct variables.

I am open to any suggestions of creating formatted/standardized tables in some alternate fashion. I intend for all my tables to have identical formatting in terms of lines, fonts, colors etc but I have not included all those aspects of the code. Right now I am getting red colored lines and unexpected end messages on the lines. Thanks

If I get this to work, I hope to do with with every repetitive procedure, indeed every procedure in my macro. Which I am guessing is how everybody does things anyway.

Comment: Will it always be a 3 and 2 columns table?

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, I intend for them to be of any size. As of today, my largest table as 10 rows and 4 columns but that might change going forward.

Comment: How are you getting the input for the tabe? Have you considered using arrays and then passing them to the funciton?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I haven't considered doing that. The numbers are computed along the way and I could just as well be re Dim-ing an array and store the numbers in some multidimensional martrix. That would be much easier. Thanks. Let me try and implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Follwing Siddharth Rout's suggestion, I did this and it works!!!!

```
   Dim tabArray As Variant

  'I defined the array of tables values outside everything because otherwise the other Sub was not able to access it.

Sub Main()




    ReDim tabArray(0 To 10, 0 To 10, 0 To 0)

    ' Apparently, you can only ReDim the last dimension, so I picked some large number for the first two dimensions, which are my rows and columns and then the last dimension will be my table title. I will keep incrementing it as I add more tables.

    tabArray(0, 0, 0) = "This table lists the number of rings won by Jordan and Kobe"

    tabArray(1, 2, 0) = "Jordan"
    tabArray(1, 3, 0) = "Kobe"

     tabArray(2, 1, 0) = "Rings"

    tabArray(2, 2, 0) = 6
    tabArray(2, 3, 0) = 5







      ReDim Preserve tabArray(0 To 10, 0 To 10, 0 To 1)


      tabArray(0, 0, 1) = "This is the transpose of the previous table"

    tabArray(2, 1, 1) = "Jordan"
    tabArray(3, 1, 1) = "Kobe"

     tabArray(1, 2, 1) = "Rings"

    tabArray(2, 2, 1) = 6
    tabArray(3, 2, 1) = 5





   Call table_mod(2, 3, 0)
    Call table_mod(3, 2, 1)



    End Sub

    Sub table_mod(row As Long, column As Long, number As Integer)





    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row




    Cells(lr + 3, 1).Value = tabArray(0, 0, number)


    For i = 1 To row
            For j = 1 To column

                   Cells(lr + 6 + i, j).Value = tabArray(i, j, number)

            Next j
    Next i



    End Sub
```

This works perfectly but it seems like a waste of space to start up from with a gigantic array. If there is some way to keep the rows and the variables bit also flexible, like maybe having an "array of arrays" where one array is a 2D array of table data and the main array contains it and contains the table name. Is this possible?

Thanks again to Siddharth Rout for suggesting Arrays.